# Matching inside tags regular expression

Tags: java, regex

From the following string that I receieve in http response:

```
<res>
    <resultCode>100</resultCode>
    <resultText>OK</resultText>
    <sessionId>60698PLA1354274623024</sessionId>
    <sessionState>OPEN</sessionState>
</res>
```

I am trying to extract sessionState (and later on sessionId) using java

I've tried following regular expressions:

```
"object containing http response".matches("\<sessionState\>.*\</sessionState\>")
```

but I never get a match. I think the problem is that i get http response in multiple lines (I've tried adding \n\s but with no luck).

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

This is the output I get with recommended regex:

```
DEBUG [1] ReplaceTags STEP for text: '"{=var.code}".matches("\\<sessionState  \\>.*\\</sessionState\\>")' is: '"<res>\r\n   <resultCode>100</resultCode>\r\n    <resultText>OK</resultText>\r\n <sessionId>60698PLA1354274623024</sessionId>\r\n    <sessionState>OPEN</sessionState>\r\n</res>'

DEBUG Executing code: "<res>\r\n    <resultCode>100</resultCode>\r\n    <resultText>OK</resultText>\r\n <sessionId>60698PLA1354274623024</sessionId>\r\n    <sessionState>OPEN</sessionState>\r\n</res>".matches("\\<sessionState\\>.*\\</sessionState\\>")

DEBUG Compiling code:
public class EvalFunction105qhjmhjn3 {
public String eval() {
    return "" + "<res>\r\n  <resultCode>100</resultCode>\r\n        <resultText>OK</resultText>\r\n <sessionId>60698PLA1354274623024</sessionId>\r\n    <sessionState>OPEN</sessionState>\r\n</res>".matches("\\<sessionState\\>.*\\</sessionState\\>");
}
}

DEBUG Eval execution returned result: 'false'
```

Comment: Why are you escaping the < and >. You don't need to.

Comment: use `xml parser`...not `regex`...

Comment: Agree.  It's harder but it works properly.  The regex only appears to work on simple xml.  sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you actually need to escape your `<>` in the first place, No documentation I've read says you need to.   [there's some documentation here](http://www.omicentral.com/cheatsheets/JavaRegularExpressionsCheatSheet.pdf)

Also, the `String.matches` method only returns a bool telling whether or not your regex is contained in the string.

you'll probably want to use the matcher and pattern classes, which are described [At this web page](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html).

Here's the relevant code sample from said page.

```
package de.vogella.regex.test;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class RegexTestPatternMatcher {
  public static final String EXAMPLE_TEST = "This is my small example string which I'm going to use for pattern matching.";

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\w+");
    // In case you would like to ignore case sensitivity you could use this
    // statement
    // Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\s+", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(EXAMPLE_TEST);
    // Check all occurance
    while (matcher.find()) {
      System.out.print("Start index: " + matcher.start());
      System.out.print(" End index: " + matcher.end() + " ");
      System.out.println(matcher.group());
    }
    // Now create a new pattern and matcher to replace whitespace with tabs
    Pattern replace = Pattern.compile("\\s+");
    Matcher matcher2 = replace.matcher(EXAMPLE_TEST);
    System.out.println(matcher2.replaceAll("\t"));
  }
}
```

and also, everyone's probably going to jump on me if i don't remind you that regex can't truly parse xml

Comment: I am forced to use regex in this case because I am working in a specific java tool.

I tried following regex:

\\<sessionState\\>.*\\</sessionState\\>

but with no luck.

Also tried

<sessionState>([^<]*)</sessionState>

also no luck :\

Comment: @user1866757  If you can make guarantees that your XML won't throw curve-balls at you, then regex can fulfill the requirement.  Just don't tell anyone else that i told you that.

Comment: well, when you run `"object containing http response".matches("\<sessionState\>.*\</sessionState\>")` a boolean will be returned.  Is that boolean for you true? or is it false?

Comment: "Also, the String.matches method only returns a bool telling whether or not your regex is contained in the string."

I am aware of that, thats why that method is followed by:

"{=var.result}".replaceAll("\<sessionState\>", "").replaceAll("\</sessionState\>", "")

Comment: @user1866757 try it without escaping the brackets, like `"object containing http response".matches("<sessionState>.*</sessionState>")`

Comment: OK, I'll try that on sunday (work time over). Man I hate regex.

Tnx to everyone that replied.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to use this regex (do not escape the angle brackets):

```
<sessionState>(.*)</sessionState>
```

And then use capture group 1 to get the value.

Also, if you don't expect any opening angle brackets in the value, I prefer this regex:

```
<sessionState>([^<]*)</sessionState>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
"HTTP response object".matches("[\\s\\S]*<sessionState>.*</sessionState>[\\s\\S]*");
```

I've removed the unnecessary escapes you had and allow for preceding and trailing characters.

EDIT: to account for newline characters